# Using Pygame + PyOpenGL, draw to a Surface instead of straight to the display?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, pygame

I'm making a lo-fi, low-resolution (1024x576) game and I was hoping I could get away with just doing supersampling (render the game at 2048x1152 then scale down) instead of proper anti-aliasing.

Trouble is, I don't see any way to render the OpenGL commands to a memory surface instead of the display surface. Is there a way?

Comment: Have you looked into working with framebuffer objects (fbos) in OpenGL? You can can create an fbo, attach a texture and then use that texture however you like. I can write an answer if you are struggling with this still.

Comment: Also SSAA even at a lowish resolution like that can be expensive. Have you looked at the default MSAA included with OpenGL? Another alternative could be a shader-based approach, like FXAA that basically blurs the image's edges.

Answer (score 0):

Using https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit you can do image.blit(image2) and use any special flags you want with that

Comment: Can't blit Surfaces to the display surface in OpenGL mode.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget: Display objects inherit from Surfaces. So you can blit the screen to another Surface and scale it down! Create a subprocess using the corresponding module, initialize Display with the `dummy` video driver (as seen in the `headless_no_windows_needed.py` Pygame example), send the Surface converted to a simple list using PixelArray, through IPC, recieve it in the main process, and blit it to a Display without OPENGL flag. You can also use FBOs.